# Change the "lgbt" tag to "lgbt+" or "lgbtq+"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, the [lgbt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) tag isn't really as inclusive as it could be - particularly when other sites like IPS SE use the more inclusive [lgbt+ tag](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/lgbt%2B/info)

I know this is hardly the biggest change in the world, but given the CoC changes and surrounding discussion I would like to put inclusivity forward and **request changing "lgbt" to "lgbt+" or "lgbtq+"**.

There are many many sexual and gender minorities, trying to open them all up could double the length of the acronum, but by simply adding in the + it really does cover all bases.

Comment: If [tag:lgbt+] is used elsewhere, then I too would support the renaming of the tag here. I suspect the downvote is just because inclusiveness is a *very* touchy subject on Stack Exchange right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

[lgbt+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b) is now the master tag. [lgbt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) and [lgbtq+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq%2b) were made synonyms and will be automatically remapped to [lgbt+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt%2b). Let me know if there are other commonly used variants we could use as synonyms.

Also, I copied the [tag wiki](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/lgbt%2B/info) from Interpersonal Skills.

Comment: I’ve heard lgbtqia+ be used before, not sure how common it is though

Answer (score 13):

I think we should rename the tag:

1. It makes the tag more accurate,
2. It brings us more in line with the tagging used on other sites
3. There's no reason *not* to make the change.
4. People will still find it if they start typing `lgbt` by @JJJ

@JJJ also points out that we should make [lgbt](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) a synonym of [lgbtq+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq%2b) to keep it from being recreated

---

Probably [lgbtq+](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbtq%2b) is the best option, because it's the most complete and only one letter longer. If anyone has objections to the "q", feel free to comment

Comment: 4. People will still find it if they start typing `lgbt`. The only downside is that [lgbt] may be created again, but it should be possible to make that a duplicate of the newer tag.

Comment: My only concern with adding more letters would be that it invites a larger debate about how many letters we need (some would say [twelve](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LGBTQQIP2SAA)). `lgbt+` is a good middle ground, in that we're expressing that some people would add more letters, and some would stop at 4. We're still getting the meaning across without being exclusive

Comment: @Machavity someone should (have) come up with a non-initialism [hypernym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypernym#Noun).

Comment: @JJJ I've seen a few users on SE use the term "Lavender" as a hypernym, but I wouldn't say it's very well-known. I don't think I've heard it used anywhere else.

Comment: @Machavity It looks like IPS uses lgbt+ . If other sites use the shorter term, then it makes sense to follow them

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on this, but Q could be troublesome if it stands for ["queer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queer) as the latter term is controversial in some LGBT circles.